# Algorithm designing

Tags: python, algorithm, graph-algorithm

Which one is more suitable for designing an algorithm that produces all the paths between two vertices in a directed graph?

- Backtracking
- Divide and conquer
- Greedy approach
- Dynamic programming

I was thinking of Backtracking due to the BFS and DFS, but I am not sure. Thank you.

Comment: are there cycles?

Comment: Between 2 fixed points or every pair of points?

Comment: If there are any cycles and if no cycles, would that change the answer? Also only between 2 fix vertices

Comment: With cycles, there are potentially infinite paths.

Comment: The comp sci stack exchange site is better for this type of question, since this isn't a programming problem per-se: https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Will do. Thank you.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50865041/781723, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/93102/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds, may I make a request?  In the future, when suggesting another site, can you let the poster know they should avoid cross-posting?  You can suggest they delete the copy here before posting elsewhere.  Hopefully this will provide a better experience for the poster and for answerers.  Thank you for listening!

Comment: @D.W. Yeah I posted it there, but it was not answered too unlike in here. So thanks to Gassa, I got an answer!

Comment: @D.W. great suggestion, I will do that in the future!

Answer (score 1):

Note that there can be an exponential number of paths in your output.
Indeed, in a directed graph of `n` vertices having an edge `i -> j` for every pair `i < j`, there are 2<sup>n-2</sup> paths from `1` to `n`: each vertex except the endpoints can be either present in the path or omitted.
So, if we really want to output all paths (and not, e.g, make a clever lazy structure to list them one by one later) no advanced technique can help achieve polynomial complexity here.

The simplest way to find all the simple paths is recursively constructing a path, and adding the current path to the answer once we arrive at the end vertex.
To improve it, we can use [backtracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking).
Indeed, for each vertex, we can first compute whether the final vertex is reachable from it, and do so in polynomial time.
Later, we just use only the vertices for which the answer was positive.

Comment: Very helpful! Thank you so much :)